# Webpages Chart for .NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

I need to easily build simple charts. My idea was to use the [Microsoft chart class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.helpers.chart?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2) to do so (as they have a very good [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart) on the subject). But this causes problems as I build a MVC webapp using .NET 5.0 and the [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages/) was made for .NET 4.7. I tried to use it anyway, but it caused errors and I want to build everything in the latest stable version of .NET and not go back to an 'older' version.

1. Is there a newer/better version for building charts in .NET 5.0/ASP.NET?
2. If not, Is there a way to get it to work?

I'm pretty inexperienced in .NET and still learning, hence this probably easy question. Couldn't find a satisfying answer online.

Answer (score 1):

It seeems that there's no version of Microsoft Chart class available for NET 5. Please check this posts:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f1e75392-ea81-4fd7-bfb8-6f4022f0c7ee/chart-control-with-net5?forum=csharpgeneral

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ms-chart-in-net-50/1297342

https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/chart-in-winform-application-with-net-c/1278500

You can check [DataVisualization](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization/1.0.0-prerelease.20110.1) as an alternative, as proposed in some of these same threads, but remember it's still a prerelease version.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a JS Chart framework, one that relies on json object to be passed, that way you can call is with an ajax call that returns json, build chart object in the controller check chart.js or c3.js.

Comment: Try to leave urls on responses like this (most important docs. But articles that sustain your affirmations also help) . This would greatly help the user that asked the question (and also increases the chances to get accepted or voted answers).